# Select query in zend framework 2.2 with multiple where clause and order by desc

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

Select query in zend framework 2.2 with multiple where clause and order by desc.

My query is

```
Select 'vch_no' from vaucher_mst where 'series_sno'=12 and vchtype_sno=13 order by vch_no,desc
```

How can I perform this query? Here is my try:

```
public function getvchno() {
    $select = new select();
    $select->from($this->table);
    $this->select('vch_no');
    $where = new where();
    $where->equalTo('series_sno',12);
    $where->equalTo('vchtype_sno',13);
    $select->where($where);
    $order_by='vch_no';
    $order=Select::ORDER_DESCENDING;
    $select->order($order_by . ' ' . $order);
    $limit=1;
    $select->LIMIT(1);
    $statement = $this->select($select);
    print_r($statement);die;
    if (!$row) {
        throw new \Exception("Could not find row $id");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Zend 2 but according to the [doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html#zend-db-sql-select), this should work:

```
// Select 'vch_no' from vaucher_mst where 'series_sno'=12 and vchtype_sno=13 order by vch_no,desc
$select = new Select();
$select->from('vaucher_mst')
       ->columns(array('vch_no'))
       ->where(array('series_sno = 12', 'vchtype_sno = 13'))
       ->order('vch_no DESC');
```

Keep me informed :)